# Observer/Observable pattern

Tags: java, observer-pattern

Quick question.

When `setChanged()` and `notifyObservers()` are called and the `Observer.update()` runs, is it in a new `Thread`, or in the same `Thread`?

Comment: This is where reading the code which is only a few lines long would answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

mainly it is in same thread. if you want you create new thread and use newly created thread in synchronize manner

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

> is it in a new `Thread`, or in the same `Thread`?

In the calling `Thread` not in a new `Thread`. It is how the `pattern` is implemented in the `java.util` package however the pattern itself could be implemented with an asynchronous way to notify the `Observers`, it mainly depends on your needs, most of the time **synchronous notifications** are what people expects but to `prevent blocking` your calling `Thread` it could be more efficient in some use cases to chose the **asynchronous notification**'s way.

Comment: Thanks for the help!